# Low performance of Word2vec for small phrases

Tags: stanford-nlp, word2vec

I am working on a course project where I have to use word2vec and glove to predict book author given a book title.
My corpus consists of 1.1M book names from different websites..many of these names are repeated( few even 500times).
My test data is a query table with few random book names( present in the corpus)
My task is to convert the book names to word vectors and compare them to the wordvectors in of main corpus and return their corresponding author names

I have tried several training parameters
Currently fixed on Word2vec( size=300, window_size=5,min_count=1,hs=1)

I tried various parameters like Playing with min-count,window size, negative sampling, using cbow, sg etc
But the models performance is not crossing 25%

I want to know the reason behind it..
I read few previous posts which said word2vec doesn't perform well with small texts as it builds on context information ..length of the book names ranges from 1 to 10 words..on an average mostly 4 words

Few posts also mentioned that training data needs to be big..Since this is the only data I've to work with, I tried upscaling it by duplicating the whole corpus several times which improved the performance but only by 2%

It's the same case with Glove

Could any of you experienced guide me how to improve the performance or if that is not possible with this usecase..a good reasoning explaining why.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost: while I understand academic assignments may be unnatural & contrived to achieve an instructional goal, this approach does not strike me as sensible, or likely to perform well.

Except in a few cases where an author coins a term, or dominates the coverage of a topic, the words of a title aren't likely to strongly suggest an author in any *generalizable* way. (Sure, with any fixed count of books, they'd work as lookup keys. That wouldn't involve any word-vectors or classifiers helping things out.)

If the real goal is a system for finding the actual authors given real book titles, finding a reference source and soing a simple lookup would be a better approach.

If there are any genuine cases where no reference answer is available, and somehow a *very poor guess* of a few likely author candidates would be valuable, something with classifiers, or the gradations of meaning available via word-vectors, might help a little. But that strikes me as both an unrealistic scenario, and one where the very-best performance (in terms of getting authors 'right') will still be very poor, no matter how well you've chosen, or tuned, your word-vectors or classifier.

So, this also doesn't strike me as a good way to learn real uses of word-vectors, or classifiers.

That said, some comments on what you've said about your approach:

- A `Word2Vec` model of parameters `Word2vec(size=300, window_size=5, min_count=1, hs=1)` already does some questionable things. `min_count=1` is almost always a mistake with such models in usual applications where they work well: words that only appear once don't have the requisite variety of usage examples to learn much of generalizable use. (Their one appearance is likely *not* representative of the word's true range-of-meaning.) But trying to make word-vectors for all those rare words will tend to *worsen* the quality of the vectors for other more-common words - by competing for training time, & model state. Further, setting `hs=1` without disabling the default negative-sampling (with `negative=0`) leads to a wasteful dual-mode model, which trains slower & takes more memory. Generally, you should either use negative-sampling (a non-zero `negative` value with `hs=0`) or hierarchical softmax ('hs=1, negative=0`), not both.
- You still have a pretty small corpus – 1.1 million titles of about 4 words each – with an unstated number of unique words (or unique words with enough different examples to make final vectors plausibly useful). *Faking a larger corpus by repeating the same texts doesn't help an algorithm like word2vec.* It needs contrasting examples, rather than repeated ones. If artificial corpus stretching seems to help, you likely could have done better just by increasing the training `epochs` instead. (That still doesn't fix the problem with too little meaningful data, but can sometimes help a bit by ensuring the model gets as much chance to learn from the liited data.)
- It is more likely that'd you'd want to remove any exact duplicate titles that are already there - to avoid overweighting cases based on idiosyncracies of your data – than increase the number of repetitions.
- Since word-vector training gives you a vector per word, *not* a vector per multi-word text (like say a multi-word title), it's not clear what you're doing when you say you "convert the book names to word vectors and compare them to the wordvectors in of main corpus and return their corresponding author names". To be clear, you'd need to describe: Convert them how? Compare them how? Choose an author to return how? (But even with the best choices for those steps, the above observations about the limits of such an approach still apply.)
- Usually for machine-learning predictive systems, you're trying to create gneralizable systems that are useful when presented with new challenges that *didn't* appear in your training data. So the most reliable testing - to get an honest estimate of how well the process works – uses test inputs that definitively *weren't* in the training data. Often, those specific known mappings used for evaluation may be *removed* ('held back') from the training corpus entirely, so that you're not testing whether the system is just 'memorizing' a cheat-sheet (with a lot of extra steps).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Understood your point regarding duplicating the corpus. I shall drop that step. stackoverflow doesn't let me give long replies. Hence splitting my reply

Comment: How is convert titles to word vectors and query them: i tokenize the titles using nltk’s word_tokenize, generate word vectors of each token and take a mean of all word vectors in a single title (like a sentence embedding) . I do the same with test query. Search for that test query’s sentence embedding in the Index (i used facebook’s faiss for index generation). I retrieve top ‘n’ matching index ids from the index and retrieve the corresponding record from the corpus. These records are supposed to contain an ‘author’ field From these records i take the author’s name. I hope i explained okish

Comment: And regarding the last point, not including the test queries in the training data would simply say word not in vocabulary. Test data is few random book titles present in the corpus.
I am looking for papers which talk about the limitations or basic requirements of a corpus like size and diversity to prove that the poor performance is partly because of them. I couldn’t find any.
Do you may be have any pointers to such papers?

Comment: That's a fair explanation, but note: (a) most sentence embeddings are *not* a simple average of all words' vectors – that's just one dirt-simple baseline approach; (b) your method of finding the closest vectors among known items, then using the best hit (or mix of top-N) to predict your new item, is essentially an ad hoc 'K NearestNeighbors' classifier. It's one simple and often effective classifier, if you have enough memory to store all known examples – but for the common (or certain?) case where your lookup title was already in the index, it essentially becomes an overcomplicated lookup.

Comment: In fact, the way you've described things – all your test titles are in the training data – I'd expect you to get 100% accuracy, except when titles are duplicated. For example, if you have `{title: 'a farewell to arms', author: 'hemingway'}`, then `wordvecs.get_mean_vector('a', 'farewell', 'to', 'arms')` will always give the same mean vector. And if that single mean vector is associated with author `'hemingway'`, so any lookup of that title will get the right answer. And every title you're looking up should already be in your index.

Comment: So if you're getting *any* wrong, you should examine the individual case to understand what's missing from your process/index. (And, all the word-vector stuff & vector-comparisons is overly complicated window-dressing - your parameters are allowing you to do a simple lookup, from a complete known reference set of titles to authors, so you might as well be using a plain Python `dict.`)

Comment: If your data is so small that holding back a few test examples would mean the model doesn't learn any word vectors for related words, that's another hint that your problem is a mismatch for word-vectors, or at least for training your own word-vectors. (You could also consider using an off-the-shelf set of word-vectors with more word coverage, or a word vector model, like FastText, that can provide guess vectors for unknonw words.)

Comment: The poor performance here is more foundational than just "corpus size & diversity". It's because once you rule-out the natural & obvious approach – obtain an authoritative mapping of title->author – then any approach based on individual words (or averages-of-word-vectors) is a very poor signal of who the authoer might be. Getting another 50 million book titles wouldn't help; the relationship of titles to authors is more arbitrary than learnable/predictable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the insights. i guess i will have to focus on data retrieval from index and understand why it not returning the obvious exact match